# Object attribute not saving

Tags: python, django

I was making a django application ,i overwrote the save method of a model to introduce a new attribute slug using sluggish fuction . But when i try to access that attribute from shell it raises an error `AttributeError: 'States' object has no attribute 'slug'`

code :-

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

class States(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    country = models.CharField(max_length = 79)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(States,self).save(*args,**kwargs)


class Colleges(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    state = models.ForeignKey(States)
    Description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Well, indeed you do not have a slug field on States. What about that is confusing you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That wouldn't work. Django would always check the initial definition of your model class to create the database mapping, django wouldn't recognize `slug` is a database field the way you do it. In your current implementation, you are only creating `slug` as a python class attribute but not database field, because django model is, well, a python class as well.

I'm not sure why you don't want to define `slug` the same way you define `title` and `country`, but the easiest fix would be adding it as a class attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to save the slug in your database, you can calculate it in a class method of `State`:

```
@property
def slug (self):
    return slugify (self.title)
```

Now you can access it as a property like title:

```
obj.slug
```